# Error 403 Forbidden When I npm install - [Node]

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I use MacBook and call npm install and got error 403 Forbidden@mobiscroll/angular@^4.10.3.

I try to type `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org` or `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org` both not work for me.

How can I fix it?

Here is log:

```
600 verbose stack Error: 403 Forbidden: @mobiscroll/angular@^4.10.3
600 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
600 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
600 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
600 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
600 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
600 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
600 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
600 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
600 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
600 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
600 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
600 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
601 verbose cwd /Users/Kevin/project/xxxx/xxxx
602 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
603 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i"
604 verbose node v10.13.0
605 verbose npm  v6.4.1
606 error code E403
607 error 403 Forbidden: @mobiscroll/angular@^4.10.3
608 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: On `npmjs.org` there is no package `@mobiscroll/angular`. Maybe you mean to install `@mobiscroll/angular-lite`